# Grouping a tables column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following is a table which has two columns **ID** and **result**,

```
ID      Result
8000010  YES
8000010  NO
8000011  YES
8000012  NO
8000023  NO
8000025  YES
8000025  YES
8000026  NO
8000026  NO
```

---

I need to aggregate in such a way that, if the **result** of particular combination of **ID** is **No** then the whole **result** is **No** else **Yes**. For example,

```
8000010 YES
8000010 NO
```

**Output**
8000010 NO

---

```
8000025 YES
8000025 YES
```

**Output**
8000025 YES

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes logixologist I have tried using 'partition over by', but did not get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by aggregation.

```
Select Id, MIN(Result)
from your_table
group by Id
```

Comment: One thing to note with this solution is that if your `result` column ever contains anything other than `Yes` or `No`, this logic **might** not work correctly since it is working on the alphabet order of the characters. Otherwise this one works great :)

Comment: you can put a where condition to filter the result which you don't want in your aggregate functions

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using CTE also, which work as generic solution as it can work across 3 or more values in result too, if we assume you have `MAYBE` also as a value

`;with new_table as (
select id, result, case when result = 'YES' then 3 when result = 'MAYBE' then 2 else 1 end as rank
from your_table) 
select id, case when  min(rank) = 1 then 'NO' when min(rank) = 2 then 'MAYBE' ELSE 'YES' end as Result from new_table
group by id`